# iOS auto-layout constraints: ignore hidden or zero-size view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

I need to horizontally layout two labels and an image:

```
[label1]-10-[icon]-10-[label2]
```

the problem is when `label1` does not have a text (ie empty text), then there is still 10 pts spacing between left edge and `icon`.

The way I am currently doing is, whenever I set any label's text, I remove all constraints and re-add them, and the spacing is depending on the text. This is obviously not efficient as the labels are in a cell which can be re-used, so every time the cell is reused, constraints are removed and re-applied.

The next thing I want to try, is to have a dedicated constraint just for `label1` and `icon`, so every time I set `label1`'s text, I'll add or remove the dedicated constraint.

I'm also wondering is there a better way to do this? It is fine if it is fundamentally changing the way I layout them.

Thanks

Comment: Actually, What do you want to do?

Comment: @PradhyumanChavda I am looking for a way to ignore label with empty text when doing auto-layout constraints, without removing / re-adding constraints.

Answer (score -1):

1. Put label1 inside a view
2. Set 10px spacing between label1's right edge and the view's right edge
3. Set constraint `[the view]-0-[icon]-10-[label2]`

Comment: How would this resolve the issue? If you explain your answer people know what you are thinking...